# Cordova + jQuery Mobile long list page optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I develop an app using Cordova + jQuery Mobile. I have some pages/screens with long lists. Potentially a list may contain unlimited number of items. I added loading of items by scrolling down. The problem is the page starts to work slow when I scroll it down and a lot of items are loaded. More items are loaded on the page more obvious become the effect of page performance slowing down. So it is not enough just to load items by scrolling down it needs to do something with the items that are invisible to user and hidden on the top.

There is collection-repeat module in Ionic framework that do what I need (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)  Is there something similar for jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no such thing in jQuery Mobile. My advice, if you're working on a hybrid application do it with Ionic. jQuery Mobile is a dead framework, nothing more, nothing else.

Comment: WOW @Gajotres, you wrote a jQuery Mobile is dead blog post and the conclusion was "jQuery Mobile is still very much alive", what made you change your mind in just 6 months? Maybe you should write another one or edit the previous.

Comment: @user2096044, as Gajotres told you, you might consider using another framework like ionic, or if you don't want to learn angular, you have kendo UI mobile, it's jquery based and I think they have an infinite list implementation.

Comment: @jcesarmobile StackOverflow changed my mind. 1-2 years ago there were almost 50 questions per day. Nowadays it only several questions per day. Though jQuery Mobile developers are still working on version 1.5 but I don't think they can stop a decline of this, once great framework. P.S. I agree with you, Kendo UI is an excellent framework for those developers who still want to use jQuery.